# html - text in a textarea without formatting?

Tags: php, html

Right now I'm taking text from one form on a page to a separate page and form. I use $_GET to get the variable and just echo out the string between the textarea tags. The problem is formatting in the php seemed to be preserved. I got an if statement in there so it's pretty off.

I tried trimming the variable but that didn't do anything. Then I stripped out the PHP and typed free hand in between the tags. Is there a way to put text in a textarea without formatting?

Comment: the problem seems to be the textarea pre formatting like a pre tag.

Comment: Code, code, code, give us code to work with we can't see what could be causing the faulty output.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by formatting?

Comment: I think OP means that the actual PHP is not getting interpreted but output in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure your file ending is .php** and that you properly open your PHP in the textarea, i.e.:

```
<textarea>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['fieldName']) echo $_GET['fieldName']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: bence de bu doğru ;)

Comment: this is the one hit the nail on the head. The problem was how I had the PHP formatted. Instead of one line like this I had it formatted out over indented lines like one normally would writing a script. The variable was getting echoed in the middle of the textarea. Putting all the PHP in one line like this solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome; textarea interprets tabs and newline characters which was probably the reason you had a lot of newlines. Have a nice weekend

Comment: You too. Didn't know that, so good to keep in mind from now on, lol.